# Mongoose TypeError: x is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a problem with mongoose model. I'm sure I did something wrong, but I cannot see what is.

This is my model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const schema = mongoose.Schema;

var account_schema = new schema({
    account_id: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    available_balance: {
        type: Number
    }
}, { timestamps = true })

module.exports = mongoose.model('account_schema', account_schema);
```

seems to be ok, so this is my post method

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const account = ('../schemas/account_schema');

router.post('/account_card/', (req, res) => {

    var account = new account();
});
```

I recieve "TypeError: account is not a constructor"

Comment: Have you forgot `require` In the file with the post method?

Comment: yes.. that's it!

Comment: I've posted it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to put `require` for the account schema

Change this:

```js
const account = ('../schemas/account_schema');
```

To this:

```js
const account = require('../schemas/account_schema');
```

But also set the variable name for the new account to be something else, like `newAccount`

Answer (score 0):

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const account = ('../schemas/account_schema');

router.post('/account_card/', (req, res) => {
//I guess you need to pass a diferent name to the var , if this dont fix the error you need to check if schema is well formed
var Account = new account();
});
```

But if you need to create a new account using that schema you need to pass the params that needs to be saved

Comment: Is useless, i instanciate like an ordinary object (as the code shown). Somehow, when i put a parameters the error still the same…. 

The model is the code in the first post…. i cannot see what is wrong 